# Perl RegEx to find the portion of the email address before the @

Tags: regex, perl, email, parsing, indexing

I have this below issue in Perl.I have a file in which I get list of emails as input.

I would like to parse the string before '@' of all email addresses. (Later I will store all the string before @ in an array)

For eg. in : `abcdefgh@gmail.com`, i would like to parse the email address and extract abcdefgh.

My intention is to get only the string before '@'. Now the question is how to check it using regular expression. Or is there any other method using substr?

while I use regular expression : $mail =~ "\@" in Perl, it's not giving me the result.

Also, how will I find that the character '@' is in which index of the string $mail?

I appreciate if anyone can help me out.

```
#!usr/bin/perl

$mail = "abcdefgh@gmail.com";

if ($mail =~ "\@" ) {
    print("my name = You got it!");
}
else
{
    print("my name = Try again!");
}
```

In the above code $mail =~ "\@" is not giving me desired output but ($mail =~ "abc" ) does.

$mail =~ "@" will work only if the given string $mail = "abcdefgh\@gmail.com";

But in my case, i will be getting the input with email address as its.

Not with an escape character.

Thanks,

Tom

Answer (score 6):

Enabling warnings would have pointed out your problem:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;

$mail = "abcdefgh@gmail.com";
__END__
Possible unintended interpolation of @gmail in string at - line 3.
Name "main::gmail" used only once: possible typo at - line 3.
```

and enabling strict would have prevented it from even compiling:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $mail = "abcdefgh@gmail.com";
__END__
Possible unintended interpolation of @gmail in string at - line 4.
Global symbol "@gmail" requires explicit package name at - line 4.
Execution of - aborted due to compilation errors.
```

In other words, your problem wasn't the regex working or not working, it was that the string you were matching against contained "abcdefgh.com", not what you expected.

Answer (score 2):

The `@` sign is a metacharacter in double-quoted strings. If you put your email address in single quotes,  you won't get that problem.

Also, I should add the obligatory comment that this is fine if you're just experimenting, but in production code you should not parse email addresses using regular expressions, but instead use a module such as [Mail::Address](http://search.cpan.org/~markov/MailTools-2.06/lib/Mail/Address.pod).

Answer (score 0):

What if you tried this:

```
my $email = 'user@email.com';

$email =~ /^(.+?)@/;
print $1
```

$1 will be everything before the @.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the index of a string, you can use the `index()` function. ie.

```
my $email = 'foo@bar';
my $index = index($email, '@');
```

If you want to return the former half of the email, I'd use `split()` over regular expressions.

```
my $email = 'foo@bar';
my @result = split '@', $email;
my $username = $result[0];
```

Or even better with `substr`

```
my $username = substr($email, 0, index($email, '@'))
```

Comment: You should use rindex in this code to look for the last @ not the first. '@' is valid in the local-part (`$username`) as a part of a quoted string according to rfc2822.

Answer (score 0):

```
$mail = 'abcdefgh@gmail.com';
$mail =~ /^([^@]*)@/;
print "$1\n"
```